# Spring Boot Security After authorization, it remains on the login form, it does not issue errors

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Why is it that when I enter my username and password and click the button, the page just reloads, does not give any errors, what am I doing wrong?
`code`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        handler.setUseReferer(true);
        return handler;
    }
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }
     
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bc=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bc;
    }
   
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
      return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
  
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);;
    http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/acthasform/").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
   .and()
   .formLogin().loginPage("/login") .successHandler(successHandler())      
   .usernameParameter("u").passwordParameter("p")            
   .permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/regulatoryform/")
   .and()
.logout().permitAll().and().
    exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
    ;
    return http.build();
}
}
```

@Component
public class Securityhandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

```
   @Override
   public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException  {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            response.sendRedirect("/regulatoryform/list.html");
        }
    }
```

}

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user=userRepository.getUserByUsername(username);
        if(user==null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find user");
        }
        return new MyUserDetails(user); 
    }
}
```

public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails{

private User user;

```
 public MyUserDetails(User user) {
       this.user = user;
    }
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    
Set<Role> roles = user.getRoles();
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
         
   for(Role role : roles) {
   authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
     }
         
        return authorities;
    }

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return user.getUsername();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return user.isEnabled();
}
```

}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login - Spring Security Example</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body div {
        text-align: center;
    }
    label, input[type=text], input[type=password] {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        width: 60px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>Spring Security Login Form</h2>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.error}">
        <h3>Invalid username and password.</h3>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
        <h3>You have been logged out.</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div><label>Username: </label> <input type="text" name="u" /></div>
        <div><label>Password: </label><input type="password" name="p" /></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Login" /></div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

My  DEBUG logs.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't use form login without a HTTP session, so remove `.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);;`

Comment: @dur thanks a lot, this has changed the situation a little, now after entering the login and password, the login form still appears, but if I manually type http://localhost:8080/regulatoryact / then the page opens, so it still does not automatically go to the desired page. I posted a new DEBUG logs. My request and response remained unchanged. If you have some free time, please take a look.

Comment: In method `onAuthenticationSuccess` is no else statement, so same page is loaded.

Comment: @dur thank you very much, the problem has been fixed, everything worked for me, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In my case, the mistake was to define sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); I removed this side.
2. In my program, I made my own component for redirection after successful authentication, but I forgot to use it in WebSecurityConfig.
   Correct code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
     @Autowired
        Securityhandler successHandler;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
 
http.authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/acthasform/").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().successHandler(successHandler).usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").permitAll().and()
.logout().permitAll().and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");

return http.build();
    }
}
```

@Component
public class Securityhandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException  {
Set roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
response.sendRedirect("/regulatoryform/");
}
else {
response.sendRedirect("/regulatoryact/");
}
}
}